# JPA-2.0 keeping all versions in DB / history

Tags: oracle, jpa-2.0, versioning

I am using JPA 2, eclipselink, Oracle DB.

Is there possibility to keep all versions in DB (history)?

Is there eclipselink/toplink switch, or should I look for special Oracle driver?

Simply said every SQL update/delete will be SQL insert.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA 2.0 itself does not provide direct support for tracking changes. Luckily EclipseLink provides HistoryPolicy extension for such a need. Rows with validity period will be persisted to the separate table when change in original table is made. Documentation is [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History).